# Get parameters from url without query string htaccess rules

Tags: php

I want to get parameters from url, instead of query string.

For Example `myhost/index.php/my_value`.

I want to get this `my_value` instead if `myhost/index.php?id=my_value`.

Any defined custom rule for this approach?

Comment: You need to define routing

Comment: check some links [link1](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) , [link2](https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute) and [link3](https://github.com/klein/klein.php) to get routing in php

Comment: @NikleshRaut thnaks for responding :) I want to keep it simple, it there not other way like to define rules in .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the request and separate in to parts.

```
$uri_segments = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo end($uri_segments);
```

Comment: This is very specific

Comment: @Abdal  Thanks for sharing, it there not other way like to define rules in .htaccess file?

Comment: @HarisKhurshid i believe it won't be a nice approach. as per Niklesh Raut you can  use routing libraries

Comment: @NikleshRaut i know since his question was very specific to get the last segment